# Confusing Button/PhotoImage/tkinter class behavior

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, the second implementation correctly shows "some_img.png" as a button background but the first does not.

```
class QuizInterface:

def __init__(self):
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Quizzler")
    self.window.config(bg=THEME_COLOR, padx=20, pady=20)

    # Example 1: Works as expected
    true_image = PhotoImage(file="./images/true.png")
    self.true_button = Button(image=true_image)
    self.true_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    # Example 2: Does not work as expected
    self.true_button = Button(image=PhotoImage(file="./images/true.png"))
    self.true_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

    self.window.mainloop()
    
    # QuizInterface object is created and called in my main.py with no error.
```

No error is thrown for the first example which is confusing. Additionally, I've noticed that I cannot define an object and then in the same line call `.grid(..)` on that object without a "function does not return anything" warning. It seems as though tkinter does not like:

1. defining multiple objects in a single line
2. pack()/grid()/place() 'ing, in the same line as object construction

Why?

Comment: Is this code in a function? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Fixed with the real code

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter images get garbage collected if there is not a reference to them. This is why your first example works and the second does not.

When you create a widget you get a reference to that widget. You can then call `pack`/ `place`/`grid` on that reference, but these functions themselves do not return anything, so assigning to them gives `None`. It's like how `a = [1,2,3].append(4)` gives `None` because `append` does not return anything but `a = [1,2,3]` and `a.append(4)` does work.

Comment: I still don't quite understand because my button doesn't appear to be None, in the first implementation. I can still pack it; I just don't see an image.

Comment: You need a reference to the `PhotoImage`. This is what gets garbage collected. In your first example you pass the `PhotoImage` straight to `Button`. Because a reference to it does not exist anywhere, it gets garbage collected.

Comment: Why is it if I set the PhotoImage to None, and pass it as the button bg, the result is different than the above case where I pass the button a non-existent reference to a PhotoImage Object?

In the former, the button is tiny, in the latter, the button is the size of the garbage collected image.

Is it garbage collecting after rendering the button?

Comment: I'm guessing (I don't actually know) that it knows the size of the image, but the image itself has been garbage collected

Comment: *"This is why your second example works and the first does not."* - It is the reverse, first one work but second one does not.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, I missed that